# ASP.Net MVC: When user active is 0 then force logout from action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried this way but no luck.

```
public class ForceLogoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var user =  UserManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

                if (user.IsActive==0)
                {
                    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
                }
            }

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }
```

in AspNetUser table i have added one column called IsActive. if it has 0 value for any user then user will be forced logout if user is already logged in. how to achieve the same from action filter. some hints is required.

i have given my two above error.

1) this line throwing error var user =  `UserManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);`

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0305  Using the generic type 'UserManager'
>   requires 2 type arguments

2) `AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);` throwing error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0122  'AuthenticationManager' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

Answer (score 3):

At last it is done. here is full code for the filter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Filters
{
    public class ForceLogoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }


        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var UserManager = filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                //var user = UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).Result; 
                var user =  UserManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).Result;

                if (user!=null && user.IsActive == 0)
                {
                    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                new RouteValueDictionary    {{ "Controller", "Message" },
                                                            { "Action", "NoAccess" } });
                }
            }


            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }

}
```

**Register this way**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Filters;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new ForceLogoutFilter());
        }
    }
}
```

code tested and working fine. thanks